# precipitate duplicate declaration

Tags: discussion

This question [Thus, what mediates the electric interaction between two particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265593/thus-what-mediates-the-electric-interaction-between-two-electrons) which in the question essentially asks:

> QTF experts say that there are no virtual particles, they are just a calculation trick. So, ok, no particle mediates the electrostatic interaction, what mediates it then?

was given as a duplicate the "[deriving the coulomb force equation from the idea of photon exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142159/deriving-the-coulomb-force-equation-from-the-idea-of-photon-exchange)

Reading the reference I do not think that the OP will be wiser even though there is a clear derivation of the coulomb force from tree level, it does not address simply  the "mediation" question,  and is , imo, way over the level of the original  OP's background.

It boils down on whether one wants layman or beginning physics questions here. It is not just the titles that should declare duplication, and I think that , as in this example, the people who jump on the "duplicate" choice have not really read the content of the one they propose in order  to check if it is on the physics background level of  the original questioner.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I disagree. The question is a clear duplicate of [Deriving the Coulomb force equation from the idea of photon exchange?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142159/deriving-the-coulomb-force-equation-from-the-idea-of-photon-exchange). I take your point that the answers to that question are somewhat technical, but the solution is to add a less technical answer to the existing question not to leave the duplicate open. I note also that the duplicate does link to [The exchange of photons gives rise to the electromagnetic force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/the-exchange-of-photons-gives-rise-to-the-electromagnetic-force) and that has some more accessible answers.

Comment: Oops, thanks Anna :-)

Comment: I edited because I think that this is the link  in the link you meant.  My comment goes to addressing the level of the question. The OP will go to the duplicate and give up that he/she could get a simple answer here. Imo , when declaring a duplicate the level of the contents should also be taken into account, not just the title.